# Passing app specific command line argument to Rails app (when starting a server)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to pass command line arguments to a Rails 3 app?  If one Rails app is to power 2 websites (one for cars and one for boats), something like

```
 rails server --site=cars
 rails server --site=boats
```

or

```
 rails server --app-argument=site:cars
```

is something like this possible?  I can only think of using in Bash

```
 SITE=cars rails server
```

and to get it in `ENV`, but command line arguments might be a more preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like a multi stage environment for this, AFAIK there isnt an easy way to pass in params via command line to do this kind of switch without some some custom hacks.

Have a look at:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/72-adding-an-environment
- http://cjohansen.no/en/rails/multi_staging_environment_for_rails_using_capistrano_and_mod_rails

Answer (score 0):

Old Question …
But still interesting.
My solution is to use Thor (In Rails 7) … it is an old Question.

I wanted / needed an "instance_number" of the Rails Server

In `boot.rb` I put

```
require 'thor'
if ARGV[0]=="s" || ARGV[0]=="server" #we won't pollute all commands
    class Thor
        # put your parameters here, as you can find in thor documents
        class_option :instance_number, type: :numeric, required: false
    end
end
```

So I put a class option into thor - but only for action server (or s). So thor takes it as needed.

This prevents Rails (if Server command) to complain about the parameter `--instance-number`

Later - where needed, I have to question about the option like this:

```
...
instance = Rails::Command::ServerCommand.new([], ARGV).options[:instance_number] rescue 0
...
```

The rescue is just for and old Rails 3 environment  where `instance_number` is useless